# What is the correct way to use git with gnome-keyring and http(s) repos?

Tags: password, git, https, gnome-keyring

Currently, whenever I `git pull` or `git push` to a http(s) repository, I get the following:

```
$ git pull
Username for 'https://gitrepos.reposdomain.com': me@mydomain.com
Password for 'https://me@mydomain.com@gitrepos.reposdomain.com':
```

This is ok for infrequent use, but starts to become really annoying very quickly.  ***Unfortunately, switching to ssh is not an option in this case.***

I've read that earlier versions of `git` provided a credential "store" and "cache", but that this wasn't advised because it stored the password in plaintext.

**BUT**

Newer versions of `git` apparently store git credentials in the `gnome-keyring`, but it has to be set up correctly.

I've tried following other (non-Ubuntu) answers on SO to get this to work (namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385690/how-to-use-git-with-gnome-keyring-integration?answertab=votes#tab-top)), but I'm still presented with the username and password prompt.

**What is the correct and safest way to store `git` credentials for http(s) repos and how does one make them work on Ubuntu?**

Comment: You should mention which methods you did try. Otherwise you might find answers suggesting exactly those.

Comment: An **entire** sentence bolded *and* italicised is hardly readable.

Comment: Upstream Debian issue to package git-credential-libsecret https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=878599

Answer (score 114, accepted):

`git-credential-gnome-keyring` is now deprecated.

Instead, use [libsecret](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Libsecret). If it's not already pre-installed on your machine, use the following procedure:

1. Make sure `libsecret` and its development libraries are installed:

   ```shell
   sudo apt install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
   ```
2. Then build the credential helper from the sources shipped with libsecret's development libraries:

   ```shell
   sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
   ```
3. Finally, register the freshly compiled binary as a [Git credential helper](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials):

   ```shell
   git config --global credential.helper \
      /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
   ```

More details on https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/2017781

Comment: You might want to note that this solution only applies to git versions >= 2.11 (where the libsecret dir may then be found)

Comment: Is this safe? Where are the secrets stored? Is both the transmission and the storage safe? Is there any official documentation? Apparently, as per [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libsecret) and [this page](https://developer.gnome.org/libsecret/), it’s in “Main” and maintained by Debian/Ubuntu. And: “It communicates with the 'Secret Service' using DBus.”

Comment: @caw: In GNOME, "Secret Service" is the same gnome-keyring-daemon, just through a different API. (The libsecret plan was to allow other DEs to build their own backends supporting the same API, e.g. KDE planned to implement this in kwalletd.)

Comment: Updating my preferred answer as I can verify this works on 18.04. :)

Comment: This appears to still be Plan A in Feb 2020. Worked on Ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: The instructions didn't work for me (not Ubuntu) but installing `gnome-keyring` (not the depricated `libgnome-keyring`) and `libsecrets` then following [Arch's wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring#Git_integration) worked.

Comment: FWIW, this worked for me a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04, but only after I rebooted (perhaps something related to installing the libsecret library?). Before reboot, git clone or anythign else that wanted to store credentials would simply hang in libsecret store op.

Comment: Is this still safe working from a shared filesystem? I would like to set this up on my university computer, but I'm concerned that /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/ is available to everyone on the network, so that other users will then be able to access my personal remote repositories

Comment: @AerinmundFagelson this is path where the compiled binary of the password manager (libsecret) is stored ; libsecret certainly does not persist the passwords in clear text on disk!

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up @eddygeek !

Comment: WORKS! Just tested on Ubuntu 20, git 2.25.1 and Unity 7.5. Didn't have to restart or anything... Quite a fresh install I should add. :)

Comment: @eddygeek how do we extend this to many other passwords?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67360592/5986651) is an answer to work with many accounts and passwords. :) The above only works for one account.

Comment: @PandianLe the main difference of *Git-Credential-Manager core* is **multi-factor** authentication. As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406012/2017781) putting the user in the remote url is enough for **multi-account**. (This technique should work with any credential helper)

Comment: Hi @eddygeek, [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67406012/2017781) was my question and VonC answered it. Vonc suggested I use a GCM. The solution is after I used gcm and updated git and added the user in the remote url. I am really unsure if it would work without this. Have you tested it?

Comment: VonC says it too "Any credential helper should follow the same process." -"Since gcm core is a bit fineky to install, test it first with the classic libsecret-based helper.".
But no, I haven't personally tested it.

Comment: Arrggghhhh sudo make. Do NOT try this at home.

Comment: @PaulChilds: Then what would *you* recommend people do instead? For users who are not experts, the advice of *"don't do this"* is not helpful if *"this"* is the only presented way to achieve what they need to do. Also, what exactly is the danger of running `sudo make` on a Makefile provided by the distribution you trust with your whole system and all your data? Sure, for random projects general it's a very bad idea (but then, `sudo make install` is equally bad for an untrusted Makefile), but in this specific instance?

Comment: sudo make is fundamentally an unsafe practice. It also will mean all build artifacts have root ownership. That sudo make is required on a system install of git is a big red flag; doubly so for a security related package. My recommendation would be for a user to install git+libsecret to their home directory where root access is not required.

Answer (score 46):

You need to setup the git [`credential helper`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential) with Gnome Keyring:

Install and compile the Gnome Keyring devel:

```
sudo apt-get install libgnome-keyring-dev
sudo make --directory=/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring
```

And setup the credential:

```
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/gnome-keyring/git-credential-gnome-keyring
```

Comment: That's really weird.  Semantically, there should be no difference between the answer in the link and this answer.  But for some reason this answer works where the other doesn't.

Comment: Then run `git push` or `git pull` as normal and the first time it will ask ansd store, and every time after that it will get it from the keyring.  To verify it, run `seahorse`.  It should be listed under "Passwords" ->"Login".

Comment: @tudor That's strange, I don't see any "conceptual" difference between my answer and the link one. Glad that it helps.

Comment: Seems weird to me that you still have to run the "make" command, but these steps work great. Thanks!

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 16.04 etc., but for Ubuntu 20.04+, you may want to use `libsecret`

Comment: Another dangerous sudo make suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

This simple approach appears to be sufficient on my Ubuntu 18.04.1 with git 2.17.1:

```
git config --global credential.helper cache
```

You can specify a one hour (=3600 seconds) timeout like this:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'cache --timeout=3600'
```

Further reading in [the fine manual](https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/).

Comment: This is helpful and the manual links to how to save to a file as well. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage. However it doesn't actually use gnome keyring.

Answer (score 0):

Try [git-credential-oauth](https://github.com/hickford/git-credential-oauth), available in [Ubuntu lunar and later](https://packages.ubuntu.com/lunar/git-credential-oauth).

> *No more passwords! No more personal access tokens! No more SSH keys!*
>
> git-credential-oauth is a Git credential helper that securely authenticates to GitHub, GitLab, BitBucket and Gerrit using OAuth.
>
> The first time you push, the helper will open a browser window to authenticate. Subsequent pushes within storage lifetime require no interaction.

Installation:

```
sudo apt-get install git-credential-oauth
```

Configuration:

```sh
git config --global --unset-all credential.helper
git config --global --add credential.helper "cache --timeout 7200" # two hours
git config --global --add credential.helper oauth
```

If you have it installed, you can also use git-credential-libsecret as a storage alternative to git-credential-cache.